# any third party dll to convert files from TIFF to PDF?

Tags: c#, pdf, converters, tiff

I want a thrid party dll to convert TIFF files to PDF using C#. I worked with ItextSharp and Tiff2PDFX tools. But I could not achieve my needs using these.

Is there any best tools to convert TIFF to PDF?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What exactly are your "needs" which you could not achieve with *iTextSharp* or with *Tiff2PDFX*??

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at .NET version of libtiff library developed by my company. It's called [LibTiff.Net](https://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) and is free and open-source (BSD License). The library comes with [tiff2pdf utility](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Tiff2Pdf) (available in source code) that probably does exactly what you need.

Disclaimer: I am one of the maintainers of the library.

Comment: Hi Bobrovsky! I could'nt find any example of usage by coding. Do you have any link which explains how use it by coding? I thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer evangelist at Aspose and I would like to share with you that [Aspose.Pdf for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx) allows you to [convert TIFF images to PDF format](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/use-image-from-local-disk.html). You may try an evaluation version at your end to see if it helps in your scenario. The complete documentation and support are also available for this component.

Answer (score 0):

The `libtiff4` project is Open Source and multiplatform. It is pretty much THE reference implementation for TIFF processing.

It also ships with a commandline tool (`tiff2pdf.exe` resp. `tiff2pdf`) that converts TIFFs to PDF and which links to the `libtiff.dll` `libtiff.so`.

If you don't reveal more details about the details that you have in mind about "*my needs*", there is not much hope that you can get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the free version of Quick PDF Library - Quick PDF Library Lite.

http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/free/lite.php

The AddImageFromFile() function will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

What are your needs?

If you use [Atalasoft dotImag](http://www.atalasoft.com)e, the conversion from TIFF to PDF is very easy:

```
public void ConvertTiffToPdf(string sourceTiff, string destPdf)
{
    using (FileStream dest = new FileStream(destPdf, FileMode.Create)) {
        FileSystemImageSource source new FileSystemImageSource(sourceTiff, true); // convert all pages
        PdfEncoder encoder = new PdfEncoder();
        encoder.Save(dest, source, null);
    }
}
```

The encoder has events that you can hook into to set PDF compression settings as well properties for setting the page fit mode, page size, passwording, document metadata, XMP, etc.

Disclaimer - I work for Atalasoft and I wrote the PDF encoder as well as the underlying library that supports it.